# No Count() for IQueryable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Normally when I use LINQ to SQL I can use Count() to get the number of records returned. However, in this case the Count() method isn't available, as if it weren't defined for the object. I'm not sure why this is happening. Here's the code:

```
        IQueryable departments;

        if (role == "ADMIN")
        {
            departments =
                db.Departments.Select(d => new {d.DepartmentID, FullName = d.Division.DivisionName + ": " + d.DepartmentName})
                  .OrderBy(d => d.FullName);
        }
        else
        {
            departments =
                db.J_DeptAdmins.Where(jda => jda.AdminUserID == userID)
                  .Select(d => new {d.DepartmentID, FullName = d.Department.Division.DivisionName + ": " + d.Department.DepartmentName})
                  .OrderBy(d => d.FullName);

            if (departments.Count() > 0) //Error is here
            {
                drpDepartment.Style.Add("display", "none");
                lblDisplayDepartment.Style.Add("display", "none");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

This is because you have declared it as `IQueryable` instead of `IQueryable<T>`.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) where all the juicy extension methods you are used to, are defined :)

Now, I see why you did it, as you are creating dynamic objects.  Consider creating a POCO class, ala:

```
public class MyPOCO
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    /* etc... */
}
```

and then have:

```
IQueryable<MyPOCO> departments;
```

and obviously, creating new `MyPOCO`s instead of dynamic objects.

**Edit**

And as D Stanley points out in the comments, if you don't want to create a POCO just for this operation, if you declare `departments` as `var departments`, you'll get the right type.

Comment: or just use `var` which will end up being a `List<{anonymoustype}>`.  Also, the result is a list of anonymous objects, not `dynamic` objects.

Comment: Can't use var departments because I need the scope to be outside of the two if blocks and if you use var you have to initialize.

Comment: If I use the POCO approach, I'm not sure how to modify my LINQ statement. I thought I could just do .Select(d => new POCO {d.DepartmentID, etc}), but that doesn't work.

Comment: Use `new POCO() { DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID, /* etc */ }`

Comment: Yep. Got it. I had a bit of bracket hell going on that caused the problem. Only thing is, I can't chain the .OrderBy because of the POCO.

Comment: Scratch that. Still get the error on .Select saying "ambiguous invocation"

Comment: @Moo-Juice, deleted the comment, found a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in a new-ish feature to c#. I used:

```
IQueryable<dynamic> departments;
```

I hadn't seen `dynamic` before, but it apparently lets you use anonymous types with generics.

Comment: This is what D Stanley was pointing out in the comments to my answer.  By using `var`, you essentially get what you have displayed above.  One advantage to the POCO method is that you get a consistent, compile-time POCO.

Comment: True, but in this case I couldn't use var because I needed the scope of departments to exist outside of the if/else blocks but I couldn't initialize it until inside the if/else blocks. More of an edge case I guess as it's the first time I've had to do it this way.